# Escaping quotes and percentage sign in SQL

Tags: php, sql, escaping

I checked similar questions but couldn't find any solution to my particular problem. I have a PHP method that I use as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM login WHERE userID = 10  //To get this 

$result = query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE userID = '%d' ", $userID) //I use this
```

so the character set '%d' is replaced by what I post in the $userID and the result is returned as JSON. Now i am trying to use it for a search function using.

```
select * from login where userName like '%searchString%'  //Now to get this

$result = query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE userName LIKE '%'%s'%'", $username) // I am trying this
```

However I got error probably due to not escaping strings properly. Is it possible for any of you to solve this with given information?

Thanks

arda

Comment: It looks like you have extra single apostrophes in there.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to change the where clause to use LIKE instead of =

```
$result = query("select * from login where userName like '%%s%'", $username)
```

I'm assuming your query method will search/replace the %s with the value of $username.One thing to be mindful is that using "select *" results in an inefficient query execution plan, you should change the * to a list of the columns from the table you want to retrieve. Also, be mindful of SQL injection attacks. See this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Answer (score 1):

you may try by  changing this '%'%s'%'

```
select * from login where userName like '%searchString%'  //Now to get this


$username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$result = query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE userName = '%%s%'", $username) // I am trying this
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping quotes and escaping percentage signs are two different matters.

First the quotes.  The bad way is to "quote the quotes", ie replace all single quotes with two single quotes.  It works, but there are disadvantages.  The better way is to use query parameters.  I don't work with php so I don't know all the details, but I read a lot of comments and answers here on StackOverflow telling php users to use prepared statements.  They may or may not escape quotes.  My guess is that they do.

For percentage signs, you have to surround them with square brackets to keep them from being treated as wild cards.  For example, if your where clause is:

```
where somefield like '75%'
```

and you want it to return

```
75% of bus passengers like singing
```

but not return

```
75 bottles of beer on the wall
```

then your where clause has to be:

```
where somefield like '75[%]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be easier than I thought. I simply passed %searchString% as an argument instead of plain searchString